# flex pop3 imap socket

Tags: sockets, apache-flex, imap, pop3

how can i communicate gmail pop server from flex
i used pop.gmail.com and port =995 using Socket() class but it returns 
220 mx.google.com ESMTP but i dont understand nothing.

Answer (score 0):

"220" is a response code from Google saying that it is ready to communicate over SMTP. There are several commands to send back and forth so you'll need to find additional information on the SMTP protocol to communicate with Google's servers.

Comment: actually i need pop protocol,by which google must return "* OK Gimap" 
style return but why 220 ???
i am astonished..i like to connect pop server on port 995 but it connects to smtp server , why?

Comment: I'm actually not sure why it's showing SMTP on port 995. That is strange.

Answer (score 0):

as3 SMTP: http://code.google.com/p/smtpmailer/

i say browse the source of that project to get a good idea of where to go.

Answer (score 0):

I made POP3/SMTP library(Airxmail) in AS3 for AIR1.5.

http://code.google.com/p/airxmail/

The site shows a sample code to connect gmail.